# Как правильно использовать мавен-профили при сборке war?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, profile

Я использую Spring + Maven + Tomcat.
Общая задача - настроить работу с профилями. 
В моем понимании, один из способов, это использовать Maven, для него в pom.xml указать профили и запускать их использую `-P {имя профиля}`.

Так же я создал `application.properties` с свойствами и его дублер по имени `application-dev.properties`. В `application.properties` так же добавил строку 
`spring.profiles.active=${spring.profiles.active}`.

Я ожидаю, что в процессе сборки `mvn clean package -P dev` в результирующем war в файле `application.properties` все значения свойств перезапишуться из `application-dev.properties`, но этого не происходит, что я делаю неправильно?

pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>at1</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Профайлы Spring можно активировать с помощью профайлов Maven, указав свойство `spring.profiles.active`.

В каждом профайле Maven можно установить это свойство:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>at1</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profiles.active>at1</spring.profiles.active>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Его значение будет использоваться для замены `@spring.profiles.active@`
 шаблона в `application.properties`:

```
spring.profiles.active = @spring.profiles.active@
```

Файлы свойств также будут использоваться, специфичные для профайла. Они должны иметь имя в формате `application-{profile}.properties`.

Cвойства в файле `application.properties` автоматически загружаются для всех профайлов, а те, которые содержатся в файлах `application-{profile}.properties` только для определенного профайла.

И вы правильно подметили для активации профайла можно использовать параметр `-P` в Maven.

Comment: в итоговом war - файле, внутри application.properties на данный момент успешно подменяется параметр spring.profiles.active  . Должны ли были подмениться остальные параметры(логопас к базе) ? Или они будут подменяться уже в момент запуска приложения?

Comment: не знал что так можно, красивая концепция, а я по старинке создаю в ресурсах отдельный каталог (conf, например) с конфигурациями (для dev, at1 и т.п.), а в профилях указываю каталог со специфичными настройками (проперти файлы и т.п.), а resources блок, соответственно, на основании настройки выбранного профиля переносит из указанного каталога-ресурса файлы

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov Остальные параметры подменяются в соответствующем профайлу `.properties` файле.

Comment: @keekkenen Это делается для ресурсов, специфичных для выбранного профайла, который включается мавеном.

Comment: @RomanC для создания и запуска интеграционных тестов, создают отдельные профили и запускают сборку с ними или другой подход?